# On Change event date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013

I'm using the sputility.js... I know the syntax to fire an on change event by activating a checkbox:

```
$(variable.Checkbox).on('change', function);
```

this also works with "Dropdown", but what do I have to use, when I want to execute a function by changing a datefield? (It is the "Due Date" - only date - no time)

```
$(variable.Date).on('change', function);
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you can try `$(variable.DateTime).on('change', function);` because SPFieldDateTime can be used for Date only fields too

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for this.
Date/Time Fields have other properties called "DateTextbox"

This works for me:

```
$(variable.DateTextbox).change(function() {
   //do this
});
```